# how use shared data sources in SQL Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I don't see any shared datasources in SQL Report Builder 3.0 although I have created one shared connection in Visula Studio Shell and deployed it so I am able to open it on web browser. Somehow it is not available within SQL Report Builder. What do I miss??
thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found it - you need to connect first to sql report server where you published your datasource.